# Javascript Or JQuery Split Alpha Numeric String

Tags: javascript, regex

Salaamun Alekum

I am trying to search JavaScript split alpha-numeric string functionality but I am not able to find it.

I want to have functionality like `Split` function in `JQuery`

Example:

```
"NewFolder333".AplhaNumericSplit();
["NewFolder","333"]///Result Splitted Array
```

Thank You

Comment: Can you add all possible input strings

Comment: Changed To split("NewFolder333");

Comment: i dont think there is any direct methods in jquery or javscript for your purpose, i would suggest you to create simple manual parser for this

Comment: @AliJamal Please stop rolling back valid edits that improve your post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do matching instead of splitting..

```
string.match(/[a-z]+|\d+/ig)
```

Answer (score 5):

tl;dr

```
<string>.match(/[^\d]+|\d+/g)
```

---

To split an Alpha Numeric String in order to obtain `["NewFolder" ,"333"]` from `"NewFolder333"` or `["section", "4", "rubrique", "2"]` from `"section-4-rubrique-2"` you can use a Regex as pattern of `match()`.

- [String.prototype.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).

The RegExp pattern will be interested you is

```
/[^\d]+|\d+/g
```

- `//` : Create a regex.
- `g` : Allow your match function to obtain all matched part.
- `[^\d]+` : Obtain a string that contain possibly all char except numeric.
- ´`|` : OR.
- `\d+` : Obtain all numeric char.

So in following code, result will contain `["NewFolder" ,"333"]`

```js
var result = "NewFolder333".match(/[^\d]+|\d+/g);
alert(result);
```

---

With a little modification, you will also be able to ignore , `_` or `-`

- `[^-_ \d]+` : Obtain a string that contain possibly all char except numeric, , `_` or `-`.

And following result will contain `["section", "4", "rubrique", "2"]`

```js
var result = "section-4-rubrique-2".match(/[^-_ \d]+|\d+/g);
alert(result);
```

or

```js
var result = "section_4-rubrique_2".match(/[^-_ \d]+|\d+/g);
alert(result);
```

or

```js
var result = "section-4 rubrique-2".match(/[^-_ \d]+|\d+/g);
alert(result);
```